# Is there any merit to "Angry 'on' you"

Tags: phrase-meaning, speech

Currently where I live there are almost ZERO English native speakers.

I love that though. Not because I seek the attention of being the only native speaker around but because it gives me the perfect opportunity to learn the other language with a  native perspective.

I hear more and more people trying to offer the phrase, *I am angry **on** you* or other flavours of this such as *I am surprised **on** you* etc.

My question is, could this be considered good English as opposed to grammar (which normally go hand in hand)? I understand the meaning behind it of course and I **like** the mental imagery of how someone can feel the possibility to place a weight *on top* of you based on their disappointment and so on.

Should I correct them or keep enjoying their broken English for my own personal entertainment ?

Comment: I visit Malaysia reasonably often where the non-indigenous population of Chinese and Indian settlers from the 19th and early 20th century have evolved their own way of speaking English. They use many of their own idioms and significantly alter some of ours. Just one example, where we use the expression 'take your sweet time' sarcastically, they will use it with sincerity to say'you just take as much time as you like and I will wait for you' - 'take your sweet time'. It is so refreshing.

Comment: The preposition itself is not so strange—clearly not something a native speaker of English would ever say, but perfectly understandable. There are quite a few other languages (many of them closely related to English, even) where you are indeed mad or angry _on_, rather than _at_, someone. But why the double pronouns? That is just confusing and strange to me. Why “I am angry [at] _you you_”? Also: what is the local language spoken where you live? (Your profile, via links, only mentions Tallaght, which does not really fit with the virtually-no-native-English-speakers bit.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the notification on the typo! :) I forget the question here will be scrutinized for grammatical correctness by definition!! :D Also while Dublin is where I was born and raised, im currently abroad which is where this chain of though arose! :)

Comment: That’s rather why I asked—‘abroad’ is a big place. Knowing what language the locals who are making these constructions speak natively is a vital key to understanding why they do it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Lithuania, I am proficient in Lithuanian and its a certainly not a direct translation!

Comment: I confess myself utterly incapable of even basic Lithuanian, but Google Translate indicates that the object of ‘angry’ in Lithuanian is either in the instrumental or preceded by the preposition _į_, which (going by Wiktionary) is ‘to(wards)’, rather than ‘on’. Interesting indeed, then, that they should choose to say, “I am angry on you”, rather than, “I am angry to you” or just, “I am angry you”.

Comment: Its a curious one.. And quite a few disassociated groups of people have said it. I guess its not grammatically correct though, which is fair enough.

Comment: Arguably this is a duplicate of [Origin of “hating on”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27640/origin-of-hating-on).

Comment: @FumbleFingers it didnt show up in my searches, should i delete this one ?

Comment: @Pogrindis: Even if the answer to *your* exact question is contained within that original post, I don't think you should actually *delete* yours. If five users here think it's a duplicate they can closevote it accordingly (or one mod could do this unilaterally, which is particularly likely if you actually *flag* the question to request this). Keeping both questions probably makes it easier for future visitors, since they've got more chance of finding what they're looking for if there are several ways to get there through search facilities. Closed questions are often useful like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no real need for them to be able to speak English perfectly, let them use these interesting titbits from other languages. As you said they are in a community where no one else speaks it - there is no reason for them to have perfect English, as long as they are understood by the people they are communicating with.

For example (I forget which language) there is a phrase that means *"Thank you"*, but literally translate as *"I will sacrifice my life for you"*. No of course they don't mean it literally, but it is interesting to hear phrases like that used.

Comment: I get what you mean and you're right, if you understand it then its ok. Do you think its grammatically correct though ? From a logical analysis of it, i see angry ON someone as the same to be angry AT someone, suggesting forward facing and directed toward, whereas andgry ON is the same just different direction.

Comment: It isn't technically correct, no.