# "Why are you hating me" or "Why are you hating on me"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Which one is the right? 
"Why are you hating me" or "Why are you hating on me"?

Comment: The one with “on” is right.

Comment: Does this question need an "idiom" tag? I would have thought it's "Why do you hate me?"

Comment: @Ry- There is no such expression as 'to hate on someone'. Colmde is correct that 'Why do you hate me' is the most natural.

Comment: @KateBunting: Yeah, there is. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hate_on

Comment: Hate used to be considered a strong word - one to be avoided.  Now, it has become trivialized to this.  What a true shame!

Comment: @user22542 Yeah, don't you hate it when that happens...

Comment: Related: [Origin of "hating on"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27640/origin-of-hating-on).

Comment: Not sure why this picked up a downvote. The current answer demonstrates that it's a valid question of usage, and worthy of being added to our site's library.

Comment: What is your intended meaning -- since they have slightly different ones?

Comment: I stand corrected. I had never come across the modern slang usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[Hate on](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hate_on)*** is, in my experience, very much [slang](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hate-hate-on.2459966/).  It has the meaning *to bestow hatred upon [someone/something], generally through insult or critique*.  If you're looking to [use the idiom in this way](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/hate-on), then the correct sentence would be:

> Why are you hating on me?

If you are trying to ask why someone dislikes you and want to use standard English, however, then you probably want to ask:

> Why do you hate me?

Comment: If the slang expression was intended, “Why do you hate me?” wouldn’t be an appropriate non-slang equivalent.

Comment: Good point, @Ry; I was unclear.  I'll reword that part of my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Hating me" and "Hating on me" have two different meanings.

"Hating me" simply relates to how a person feels about you - generally reflecting an intense dislike but not necessarily consciously acting on that feeling.

"Hating on me" refers to their actions in relation to their feelings about you. For example, if they are acting on their hatred for you by purposefully making hateful or damaging remarks about you or acting in a way that is intended to cause reputational or physical damage to you.